# How to start reading from second row using CSV data config element in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

CSV data config always reads from first row. I want to add column headers in the CSV file. Hence I want the CSV config to start reading from second row.

Below is the setting in Thread Group.
No.of threads = 1
Loop Count= 10 (depends on no.of rows in CSV file)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What version of JMeter are you using? It seems like leaving the `Variable Names` field empty will do the trick. More info [here](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54389):

> Versions of JMeter after 2.3.4 support CSV files which have a header
>   line defining the column names. To enable this, leave the "Variable
>   Names" field empty. The correct delimiter must be provided.

Comment: thanks @Jake... I am using Jmeter2.11, Leaving the variables name blank in CSV config and specifying column headers in CSV file solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

1. Leave the variable names empty like on an attached snapshot.

[image]

2. In csv file add header. Header values will act as variable names which could be used as parameters in requests. 
   ~sample facility.csv file
   facility1,name 
   GG1LMD,test1
3. Request

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a field called "Ignore first line (only used if Variable Names is not empty)", set this to true.

[image]